# Instantaneous window close on double-clicking python icon

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-10, conda

I am having a problem in windows-10 when double clicking a python script that will run normally from the anaconda prompt. I have reduced this to a trivial case. The window does not actually close on the double click, it is one one of the first imports. Several will do this but in the case shown it is the "import numpy as np". This test.py shown below runs fine as "python test.py" but crashes on the numpy when I double click. In both cases it prints the "running interactively. Any help will be most appreciated. I should say that initially I did not have this problem. I screwed up anaconda and had to do a complete reinstall. When this happens I always save the install history so I put up the same packages. This is up-to-date windows-10 and I always finish my anaconda install with update --all.

```
#help
#help()
input("cr0:")
import sys
if sys.stdin.isatty():
# running interactively
    print("running interactively")
else:
    with open('output','w') as f:
    f.write("running in the background!\n")
input(" <CR> 1 to exit:")
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os
from io import StringIO
import sys
import platform
input(" <CR> 3 to exit:")
import tkinter as tk
input(" <CR> 6 to exit:")
import numpy as np
input(" <CR> 5 to exit:")
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
input(" <CR> 4 to exit:")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
input(" <CR> 2 to exit:")
```

Comment: Personally I've had a lot of trouble getting python programs to work properly using anaconda on ms-windows. So I would suggest using the windows installers from python.org (3.7 or later). Those have caused me a lot less trouble.

Comment: I'm running Anaconda and can double-click icons.  What do you have associated with a double-click?  What's printed out on the console when it crashes?  I would add some prints to figure out exactly what version of python is running, etc, from inside your code.  What happens when you right click and choose Open With?

Comment: Can you run it from the command line/terminal successfully?

Comment: There is nothing printed on the console when it crashes. More precisely, if anything is printed the console closes before it can be seen. I wanted to set some switch so python would print every niggling half-an-error to see something. Could not figure out how to do that. If I change the order of imports it will crash on something else; e.g., pandas. As I said, the anaconda prompt; python test.py always works. That is where I wanted to see some sort of minor error.